# How to update patch color based on a turtle occupation radius?

Tags: netlogo

In the set up mode, when my turtles are sprouted, they occupy different patch's radius according to breed.
However, when they move, I can't update the patches of the radius, only the patches where they are located.

```
patches-own [occupied? ID]
breed [rico ricos]
breed [pobre pobres]

to create-agents
ask patches with [ID > 5 and occupied? = false] [sprout-ricos 1
ask patch-here [set occupied? true set pcolor red]
ask patches in-radius ricos [set occupied? true set pcolor red]
]

ask patches with [ID < 5 and occupied? = false] [sprout-pobres 1
ask patch-here [set occupied? true set pcolor blue
ask patches in-radius pobres [set occupied? true set pcolor blue]
]

end

to move
ask turtles [fd 20]
end

to update-patches
ask patches [
  if (not any? turtles-here) [
      set pcolor white
      set occupied? FALSE
    ]
end
```